# Django ORM: filter primary model based on chronological fields from related model

Tags: python, django

Let us presume that we have the following models:

```
class Patient(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    # other fields following

class MedicalFile(model.Model)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='files')
    date = models.DateField()
    diagnostic = models.CharField()
```

We want to build a viewset for patients where we want to filter the Patient records based on their last available/valid diagnostic.

I don't know how to solve this without using raw SQLs. Is there an optimal way to build this statement using only Django query set syntax ?

---

**How did I solve this ?**

I'm sure this isn't nice, but it's optimal for filtering large datasets.

The idea is to use a view implemented at the database layer, where we will query all the patients with their associated latest medical file, than to map a Django entity to that view. Of corse, we will make the new model as un-managed.

Why to go such a long way ? Because on the new model we could use "re-usable" Django query syntax. Of corse, the view from the database isn't re-usable and has to be re-created for each db backend solution.

Considering Postgres, this would be the view definition:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    f.*
FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            *,
            max(date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id) AS latest_date
        FROM MedicalFile
    ) AS mf ON mf.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE
    mf.latest_date IS NULL OR mf.latest_date = mf.date
```

Then we could create the associated model like this

```
class LatestMedicalFile(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField(Patient, related_name="latest_file")
    date = models.DateField()
    diagnostic = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '<your view name here>'
```

Finally, our query can be written like this:

```
Patient.objects.filter(latest_file__diagnostic='flu')
```

This is not intuitive, nor clean, in my opinion. Any ideas ?

Comment: So basically, order by date in Files?

Comment: ... yes, partition over by Patient.id. There is a challenge (for me) to get a representation where in the same record (query row) I get the patient data and the data (diagnostic in this case) from the latest available patient file.

Comment: May you show your SQLite you expect?it should can convert quesryset  styntax.

Comment: I know how to do this with 2 queries, used that patterns before, never been very fond of it thou....

Comment: May you show your sql styntax ?

Comment: In pure SQL this can be achieved using something window functions over partitions. For the given example, consider that we want to filter after the diagnostic "flue":

SELECT
  p.name
FROM Patiens p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      mf.patient_id 
      mf.diagnostic,
      max(date) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id) AS latest_date
    FROM MedicalFile mf
  ) AS f ON f.patient_id = p.id
WHERE
  f.diagnostic = 'flue' AND f.date = f.latest_date;

Comment: @Beltiras: how would you achive it with 2 queries ?

Comment: Actually, I found a single-query solution, will answer with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in seeing the files:

```
MedicalFile.objects.annotate(
    maxdate=Max(
        'patient__files__date'
        )).filter(
            maxdate=F('date'),
            diagnosis="flu").select_related(
                'patient'
            )
```

If you want the patients:

```
Patient.objects.annotate(
    maxdate=Max(
        'files__date'
        )).filter(
            maxdate=F('files__date'),
            files__diagnosis="flu"))
```

Great thanks to [Roba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3925926/roba), collaborative asking/answering is my favourite type of SO user.

Comment: Doesn't suffice: what if a patient has his latest file < comp_date ? Is still his latest valid file ... and the query will skip it.

Comment: I radically misunderstood the query.  Your updated questions requires me to think about it but I'm sure I can come up with something natural without resulting to raw.

Comment: Any help to crack this nut really appreciated on my side ... thanks man.

Comment: Can you confirm for me if this did what you are asking?  It's a neat pattern.

Comment: It works with MedicalFile.objects.annotate(latest_date=Max('patient__files__date')).filter(latest_date=F('date')).select_related('patient'); I'm testing it with a bit more data.

Comment: Yeap, it's a neat trick, forcing a second left outer join there. That's why in this case the result it's correct in contrast when you're making the aggregate on the primary table. Please update your answer so I can flag it as correct.

Comment: I've followed up on your technique. It seams to work even if you're using the primary table, because an additional join is being introduced, together with the having clause: Patient.objects.annotate(latest_date=Max('files__date')).filter(latest_date=F('files__date'), files__diagnostic='flu'). Please update your answer so I can flag it as correct.