# Django ORM: django aggregate over filtered reverse relation

Tags: django, django-queryset

The question is remotely related to [Django ORM: filter primary model based on chronological fields from related model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017030/django-orm-filter-primary-model-based-on-chronological-fields-from-related-mode), by further limiting the resulting queryset.

## The models

Assuming we have the following models:

```
class Patient(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    # other fields following

class MedicalFile(model.Model)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='files')
    issuing_date = models.DateField()
    expiring_date = models.DateField()
    diagnostic = models.CharField()
```

## The query

I need to select all the files which are valid at a specified date, most likely from the past. The problem that I have here is that for every patient, there will be a small overlapping period where a patient will have 2 valid files. If we're querying for a date from that small timeframe, I need to select only the most recent file.

More to the point: consider patient John Doe. he will have string of "uninterrupted" files starting with 2012 like this:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|ID |issuing_date|expiring_date|
+---+------------+-------------+
|1  |2012-03-06  |2013-03-06   |
+---+------------+-------------+
|2  |2013-03-04  |2014-03-04   |
+---+------------+-------------+
|3  |2014-03-04  |2015-03-04   |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

As one can easily observe, there is an overlap of couple of days of the validity of these files. For instance, in 2013-03-05 the files 1 and 2 are valid, but we're considering only file 2 (as the most recent one). I'm guessing that the use case isn't special: this is the case of managing subscriptions, where in order to have a continuous subscription, you will renew your subscription earlier.

Now, in my application I need to query historical data, e.g. give me all the files which where valid at 2013-03-05, considering only the "most recent" ones. I was able to solve this by using RawSQL, but I would like to have a solution without raw SQL. In the previous question, we were able to filter the "latest" file by aggregation over the reverse relation, something like:

```
qs = MedicalFile.objects.annotate(latest_file_date=Max('patient__files__issuing_date'))
qs = qs.filter(issuing_date=F('latest_file_date')).select_related('patient')
```

The problem is that we need to limit the range over which latest_file_date is computed, by filtering against 2013-03-05. But aggregate function don't run over filtered querysets ...

## The "poor" solution

I'm currently doing this via an extra queryset clause (substitute "app" with your concrete application):

```
reference_date = datetime.date(year=2013, month=3, day=5)
annotation_latest_issuing_date = {
    'latest_issuing_date': RawSQL('SELECT max(file.issuing_date) '
                                  'FROM <app>_medicalfile file '
                                  'WHERE file.person_id = <app>_medicalfile.person_id '
                                  '  AND file.issuing_date <= %s', (reference_date, ))
}
qs = MedicalFile.objects.filter(expiring_date__gt=reference_date, issuing_date__lte=reference_date)
qs = qs.extra(**annotation_latest_issuing_date).filter(issuing_date=F('latest_issuing_date'))
```

Writen as such, the queryset returns correct number of records.

Question: how can it be achieved without RaWSQL and (already implied) with the same performance level ?

Comment: Somewhere along these lines django allows nested filtering that behaves the way one expects: `qs = MedicalFile.objects.filter(id__in=self.filter(patient=john_doe, expiring_date__gt=reference_date, issuing_date__lte=reference_date)).latest('issuing_date')`

Comment: latest returns the latest record from within the table. we need the latest file for a patient, but within a resultset comprising of all the possible patients.

Comment: That's why you 'pre-filter' with `id__in`

Comment: OK, for one patient this could work. But what about the original question: retrieve all the files which are valid at a certain date ? (no matter how many patients).

Comment: You may try to remove the patient from the nested filter and use `order_by('patient__pk', '-issuing_date').distinct('patient__pk')` instead of `latest('issuing_date')`. But `distinct` with field names, I think, is only supported by Postgres.

Comment: You're onto something here. It looks that the solution is to use order_by and distinct. Preferably in a sub-query and then compose the result by filtering for specific folder_pks - this way one can perform ordering of the resulting queryset for display purposes. If you update your answer like this, I will rate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `id__in` and provide your nested filtered queryset (like all files that are valid at the given date).

```
qs = MedicalFile.objects
.filter(id__in=self.filter(expiring_date__gt=reference_date, issuing_date__lte=reference_date))
.order_by('patient__pk', '-issuing_date')
.distinct('patient__pk')  # field_name parameter only supported by Postgres
```

The `order_by` groups the files by patient, with the latest issuing date first. `distinct` then retrieves that first file for each patient. However, general care is required when combining `order_by` and `distinct`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

**Edit:** Removed single patient dependence from first filter and changed `latest` to combination of `order_by` and `distinct`

Comment: aaahm... not sure it works... Again: I need to query all the files which are valid at a certain date; if there are multiple files per patient, then we should consider only the most recent one. Your clause will retrieve only one file (supposedly for only one patient). What about all the files no matter who the patients are ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider `p` is a Patient class instance.

I think you can do someting like:

```
p.files.filter(issue_date__lt='some_date', expiring_date__gt='some_date')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Or maybe with the `Q` magic query object...

Comment: Yes, I'm already filtering like this, see the first part of the result queryset. The issue is that the aggregation function Max will consider all the records from the backward relation.

Comment: Then add something like `.order_by('-issuing_date')[0]`

Comment: aaahm... not sure it works... Again: I need to query all the files which are valid in a certain date; if there are multiple files per patient, then we should consider only the most recent one. Your clause will retrieve only one file (supposedly for only one patient).